# Rounded buttons in XCode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, button, uibutton, storyboard

I have been looking for an answer to this question on google and other places, but have not found a helpful answer as of yet.

I am making an app on Xcode 4.6 using storyboards.

When drag and drop a Rounded Rectangle Button, it is fine, but when I change the background, it becomes rectangular with no rounded edges. i just wanted to change the colour of button and not anything more, but keep it rounded as the original buttons. Could someone tell me a simple method to achieve this or give me a detailed instruction as I am using storyboard and I am rather poor with XCode programming, so the little the programming, the better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are using a background image or a background color?

Comment: Yes I'm using background,, background colour isn't possible for round rectangle buttons I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

I have used an alternative method as I do not understand the suggestions which were given to me as I am not as knowledgeable about XCode programming and didn't want to take the coding route.

This may be useful for others, but what i done was that I in Photoshop, I filled the background black, used the rounded rectangle tool on the whole background and then filled the rounded rectangle with the button colour. This somewhat gave a rounded shape, but is still not as good as the original rounded buttons provided in XCode.

If anyone has any other solutions, I am free to try them out and will comment and update what I will do.

I will select the best answer by looking at which one was the simplest although I have not used that method

Comment: I will not select this as the accepted answer as this is not the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should check the [UIAppearance Protocol documentation for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance).

Meanwhile, you can use...

```
    [[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

of course, with your color.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use GradientButtons

http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/downloads/list

1) Define regular buttons in your storyboard files.

2) Change their class to GradientButton.

3) If you want a different color, initialize them in the corresponding view.